# Are there law firms that reputedly specialize in techniques or functions, rather than subject matter?

Tags: united-states

By "subject matter" I refer to branches of law such as torts, criminal law, environmental law, etc.

By "techniques or functions" I refer to things like cross-examination, or forensic analysis, that is constructing fact sets or time lines to beat the opposition. Or the following:

Suppose I'm dealing with an opponent who has made mutually inconsistent or contradictory assertions in previous proceedings. Are there law firms that specialize in catching and highlighting such inconsistencies in court?

Comment: Unless you were a party to those proceedings, the inconsistency is largely irrelevant to your proceeding.

Comment: @DaleM: "I" (my friends actually) were a party to the earlier proceedings. They're using a different lawyer for a related case.

Comment: There is definitely no official recognition of such specializations and some jurisdictions prohibit lawyers from even claiming such a specialization as a matter of professional ethics.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're talking about is probably quite rare.

There are certainly law firms that market their ability to thoroughly investigate the facts, aggressively question or impeach hostile witnesses, present compelling evidence at trial, or make persuasive oral arguments. But I don't think I've ever heard of a firm that treats any particular litigation tactic as its specialty *rather than* treating it as part of its specialization in domestic relations, DUI defense, employment law, etc.

If you think of litigating at *different stages* of a case as "techniques or functions," then I'd point to the various firms that consider themselves trial specialists, or appellate specialists, or even Supreme Court specialists. Even then, though, any of those specialties is going to involve a variety of discrete techniques or functions. A trial lawyer needs to do investigations and cross examinations and closing statements, and a Supreme Court specialist needs to be able to petition for cert, draft merit briefs, and give oral arguments.

Comment: I think the situation is the one you mentioned, the proceedings are moving to a different stage, and some lawyers are better at different stages than others.

Answer (score 3):

There are firms that do specialized things for attorneys like patent searching, analyzing gigabytes of digital data from discovery (or for discovery), and the traditional private investigators digging up facts and locating witnesses. They are not law firms but might employ lawyers.